# Best way to intercept a network call and providing mock response while UI testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, retrofit2, android-espresso

I am testing a login page on an android project and would like to intercept when the call is being called (When a button is clicked) and provide with a mock response (200 or 401 for ex) to prevent actually calling the network every time and to make automated unit testing faster. I usually just provide correct username/pass and Thread.sleep for a few until the request is done and I know this is not the correct way.

I am using retrofit 2 for my network calls and Espresso for UI testing.

I know how to mock a retrofit call but I want to mock exactly when the call is being executed in the login activity and send that activity a mock response.